# Append String to file name in dos Syntax Error Need

Tags: batch-file, dos, rename

```
@ECHO off
title Rename Script
set dir1=%1
set STR=%2
set count=1
:Start
cls
echo 1. Rename Files
echo 2. Quit
set /p choice=I choose (1,2):
if %choice%==1 goto rename
if %choice%==2 exit
:rename
cls
echo Running Rename Script for STR=%STR%
FOR %%n in (%dir1% *.*) DO (
ren %%n %STR%%%n
echo %STR%%%n)
echo done
pause
```

C:>yogesh>LDK.bat C:\yogesh app

OUTPUT:

```
Running Rename Script for STR=app
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
appC:\yogesh
appa3dapi.dll
appHLTV-Readme.txt
apphltv.cfg
appkver.kp
applanguage.inf
appLDR.bat
appMp3dec.asi
appMss32.dll
appMssv12.asi
appMssv29.asi
appTrackerNET.dll
The batch file cannot be found.

C:\yogesh>
```

There are few issues with this script:

1. " The syntax of the command is incorrect." I do not know where is the problem in script.
2. How to get the count of number of files renamed ?
3. Files get renamed into the directory where the .bat file resides I want to rename the files in specified folder as argument in variable **dir1**

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: remove the @echo off from the start (or `REM` it out) and you can see what commands are being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
@ECHO off
title Rename Script
set /A count=1
:Start
cls
echo 1. Rename Files
echo 2. Quit
set /p choice=I choose (1,2):
if %choice%==1 goto rename
if %choice%==2 exit
:rename
cls
set /p STR=choose a start-string:
echo Running Rename Script for STR=%STR%
FOR %%n in (*.*) DO (
ren "%%n" "%STR%%%n"
echo "%STR%%%n"
set /A count+=1)
echo count %count%
echo done
pause
```

1. we can save the current path in OLDDIR and then change the path to the one the user gave, at the end of the script we'll go back to OLDDIR using `CD`
2. you need to set the counter with `/A`

**UPDATE for dbenham:**
A small proof :)) that it worked (for me) with filenames that contains spaces:

[image]

Comment: One more thing please: how to rename files names having space ?

Comment: for me it worked with filenames that contain spaces, but if it doesn't work for you, try wrapping the filename with ""

Comment: Simpler to use PUSHD/POPD instead of storing value in var and using CD. Don't see how the script can work with names containing spaces unless quotes are added.

Comment: Very curious. I get a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error on Windows 7 when trying to rename a name with spaces unless I put quotes around both the source and target. One unrelated thing - you probably should initialize the count variable before entering the loop.

Comment: it's being initialized on the 5th row. This script works - I tested it (as you can see from the update).

Comment: I would like to copy this file to the selected folder and then after double clicking this script all the files in that folder should be renamed. This is not working I couldn't get the path of folder where that file resides frm the script.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using CD. You needed to put a `\` between your dir1 variable and `*.*` instead of a space. You needed quotes to protect against spaces in names. Use FOR variable modifiers `~nx` to get just the name and extension (removes any drive and path info). Finally, use SET /A to perform math.

```
@ECHO off
title Rename Script
set "dir1=%~1"
set "STR=%~2"
set count=1
:Start
cls
echo 1. Rename Files
echo 2. Quit
set /p choice=I choose (1,2):
if %choice%==1 goto rename
if %choice%==2 exit
:rename
cls
echo Running Rename Script for STR=%STR%
set cnt=0
FOR %%F in ("%dir1%\*.*") DO (
  ren "%%F" "%STR%%%~nxF"
  echo %STR%%%~nxF
  set /a cnt+=1
)
echo %cnt% files were renamed.
echo done
pause
```

Comment: I would like to copy this file to the selected folder and then after double clicking this script all the files in that folder should be renamed. This is not working I couldn't get the path of folder where that file resides.